# Подключение obj файла к проекту в MSVS12

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Всем привет!
Есть следующий вопрос: допустим есть объектный файл, в котором находится нужная функция - каким образом подключить ее к пишущемуся проекту (к файлу cpp)?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в опции компоновщика:

Правой крысой по проекту -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies -> Edit -> добавляете вашу библиотеку. Либо полный путь, либо относительно Additonal Library Directories.